# Opengl: print more string with glutBitmapCharacter

Tags: c++, opengl

I've to print more string in OpenGL. I know how to print a single string and I've create this function for print more string:

```
...
void printRasterw(float x, float y, float z, char* string)
{
   char * pch;
   float lineSpace = 18.0f;

   pch = strtok (string,"\n");
   while (pch != NULL)
   {
       glRasterPos3f(x, y, z);
       glutBitmapCharacter(GLUT_BITMAP_HELVETICA_18, atoi(pch));
       pch = strtok (NULL, "\n");
       y -= lineSpace;
   }
}
...
```

and

```
...
void drawText()
{
   glPushMatrix();
   glLoadIdentity();
   glColor3f(1, 1, 1);
   printRasterw(-0.9,  0.9, 0.0, "teapot \n spoon");
   glPopMatrix();
}
...
```

But it doesn't work (when I compile, g++ return me segmention fault error). How I can resolve this problem? Or everyone have an other solution for do this? Thanks.

Comment: What exactly are you hoping to achieve with that `atoi()` call?  Just cast to `int`.

Comment: @genpfault cast to `int` give me this error: `error: cast from ‘char*’ to ‘int’ loses precision [-fpermissive]`. I've solved with `g++ -fpermissive` but I've segmentation fault error yet.